Tiling a $2\times12$ chessboard with $1\times 2$ and $1\times 3$ cardboards.
This is problem 9.102 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
One is given a $2\times 12$ chessboard and an ample supply of $1\times 2$ and $1\times 3$ card boards. Numbers $1,2,...,12$ and $13,14,...,24$ are written in each unit square, in that order from left to right, in the top and bottom row, respectively. In how many ways can the chessboard be tiled by a collection of card boards.
I attempted to solve it this way.
Let $a_n$ be the number of ways to tile a $1\times n$ chessboard with $1\times2$ and $1\times3$ card boards. If a tiling of $1\times n$ chessboard ends with a $1\times 2$ cardboard, we may remove that $1\times2$ cardboard to obtain a $1\times(n-2)$ chessboard tiling. If it ends with a $1\times 3$ chessboard, we may remove that $1\times3$ cardboard to obtain a $1\times(n-3)$ chessboard tiling. So we have
$$a_n=a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$$
Using the initial conditions $a_1=0$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=1$ and the recurrence relation, we obtain $a_{12}=9$.
The number of ways to tile a $2\times12$ chessboard is given by $a_{12}^2=81$.
One thing I'm confused about is the numbering of the unit squares. In the above attempt, I have not used the fact that the unit squares are numbered. So I would like to ask whether my attempt is correct and if there's anything important about the numbering of the unit squares.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

If I understand your solution, you are not considering when a $1\times2$ tile is used vertically in the covering of the $2\times 12$ rectangle.

You understood correctly. I'm not sure if that is correct or not. Moreover, if I have to consider the cases where a tile is used vertically, then I'm not sure if recurrence relation even works since the number of cases to consider seem to be too many.

This is A129682, which has some more formulae.

I would use two recurrence relations:

$a_n$ is the number of ways to tile a $2\times n$ rectangle.
$b_n$ is the number of ways to tile a $2\times n$ rectangle that is missing one corner square.

With a rectangle, there are only a few ways to fill the first column:

Vertical domino, leaves a $2\times (n-1)$ rectangle with $a_{n-1}$ ways to tile
Horizontal dominos, leaves a $2\times (n-2)$ rectangle with $a_{n-2}$ ways to tile
Horizontal trominos, leaves a $2\times (n-3)$ rectangle with $a_{n-3}$ ways to tile
Horizontal domino and tromino, leaves a $2\times (n-2)$ rectangle with corner missing with $2b_{n-2}$ ways to tile, where the factor 2 is because the domino/tromino can be in either order.

This gives the relation $a_n= a_{n-1} + a_{n-2} + a_{n-3} + 2b_{n-2}$.
A rectangle with a corner missing also has only a few ways to fill the first part:

Horizontal domino, leaves a $2\times (n-1)$ rectangle with a corner missing with $b_{n-1}$ ways to tile
Horizontal tromino with a horizontal domino next to it, leaves a $2\times (n-3)$ rectangle with $a_{n-3}$ ways to tile
Horizontal tromino with another horizontal tromino next to it, leaves a $2\times (n-3)$ rectangle with a corner missing with $b_{n-3}$ ways to tile

This gives the relation $b_n= b_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + b_{n-3}$.
Then just find some initial values, which is straightforward:
$a_0 = 1$, $a_1 = 1$, $a_2 = 2$
$b_1 = 0$, $b_2 = 0$, $b_3 = 1$
Now you can just plug in the values until you get to $n=12$.



$n$
$a_n$
$b_n$




$0$
$1$
$0$


$1$
$1$
$0$


$2$
$2$
$0$


$3$
$4$
$1$


$4$
$7$
$2$


$5$
$15$
$4$


$6$
$30$
$9$


...
...
...




If I understood correctly, $b_n$ should be the number of ways to tile a 2×n
rectangle that is missing the top left corner square. However, the similar formula given here https://oeis.org/A129682 which uses the notation $r(n)$ in place of your $b_n$ has the formula $r(n)=r(n-1)+r(n-2)+a(n-2)$. Does that mean the formula given in that encyclopedia page incorrect?

@19021605 Yes, I think they typed the indices wrong on that one, accidentally using n-2 instead of n-3. My table matches the actual series.

Please note that this answer does not provide a rigorous combinatorial explanation.
Consider two values $x$ and $y$ to indicate how many items are left in the top and bottom row respectively. If $x = y$, then we can have at the end:

One vertical $2 \times 1$ block
Two horizontal $1 \times 2$ blocks
Two horizontal $1 \times 3$ blocks
One horizontal $1 \times 3$ block at the top and one horizontal $1 \times 2$ block at the bottom
One horizontal $1 \times 2$ block at the top and one horizontal $1 \times 3$ block at the bottom

If $x \ne y$, we have to assign a $1 \times 2$ or a $1 \times 3$ block at the end of the longest row.
The recurrence relation we are looking for is thus the following:
$$
f(x, y) = \begin{cases}
    f(x - 1, y - 1) + f(x - 2, y - 2) + f(x - 3, y - 3) \\
    + f(x - 3, y - 2) + f(x - 2, y - 3) & \text{if } x = y \\
    f(x - 2, y) + f(x - 3, y) & \text{if } x > y \\
    f(x, y - 2) + f(x, y - 3) & \text{if } x < y
\end{cases}
$$
The following Python code solves this for $(x, y) = (12, 12)$:
def f(x, y):
    # eliminate invalid values
    if x < 0 or y < 0:
        return 0
    # define base conditions
    if (x, y) == (0, 0):
        return 1
    # use recursion
    if x == y:
        return f(x - 1, y - 1) + f(x - 2, y - 2) + f(x - 3, y - 3) + \
               f(x - 3, y - 2) + f(x - 2, y - 3)
    if x > y:
        return f(x - 2, y) + f(x - 3, y)
    return f(x, y - 2) + f(x, y - 3)


print(f(12, 12))

The answer is $f(12, 12) = 2093$.

I don't know that the numbering on the squares matters. Certainly the exercise could leave that out, and if that numbering were helpful in a solution, then you could decide to induce that numbering yourself.
You have a recurrence relation for $a_n$, good. Where $a_n$ is the number of ways to tile the $1\times n$ rectangle. But when tiling a $2\times n$ rectangle, we might use a $1\times2$ tile, but oriented vertically (so, a $2\times1$ tile), and then the final answer to this is not as simple as $a_{12}^2$.
Suppose there are $k$ such vertical $2\times1$ tiles in a tiling. In between them, if there is any space at all to tile, all tiling is with horizontal tiles. So we have:

$k=0$. We get your $a_{12}^2$
$k=1$. We get $\sum_{j=1}^{12}a_{j-1}^2\cdot a_{12-j}^2$ by summing over all the places that one tile could go, and applying your reasoning to the left rectangle and the right rectangle.
$k=2$. We get $\sum_{j_1=1}^{11}\sum_{j_2=j_1+1}^{12}a_{j_1-1}^2\cdot a_{j_2-j_1-1}^2\cdot a_{12-j_2}^2$ by similarly summing over the locations those two vertical tiles could land.
and so on...
$k=9$. You'd have to have a $2\times3$ gap of horizontal tiles. There are $10$ ways to do that.
$k=10$. You'd have to have a $2\times2$ gap of horizontal tiles. There are $11$ ways to do that.
$k=11$. No such tiling is possible.
$k=12$. There is only one way to tile with $k=12$.

This enumeration is tedious but maybe there is a clever simplification.
